# Using IPC_CREAT with an already created shared memory segment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, c, shared-memory

I am trying to figure out what will happen if I use the  `IPC_CREAT` flag with `shmget()`. I have used a key of an already created shared memory segment from another process. When I did so, the calling process has shared actually this memory segment with the old process ( For sure I have attached this memory segment using `shmat()`). So can I conclude that if I use  `IPC_CREAT` with a shared memory segment that is already created the effect is that this memory will be shared with the calling process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the idea. You use `IPC_CREAT` to *allow* the creation, not to force it. To force creation (and failure if the key already exists), `IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL`.